# Are Australians allowed to visit Nauru as tourists?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens, nauru

Are Australians allowed to visit Nauru as tourists?

I heard media reports a while ago about restrictions on Australians and New Zealanders. Neither [smartraveller.gov.au](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/pacific/Pages/nauru.aspx) nor New Zealand's [Safe Travel](https://www.safetravel.govt.nz/nauru) issue travel advice for Nauru, and I couldn't visit [Nauru's page on visa requirements](http://www.naurugov.nr/about-nauru/visiting-nauru/visa-requirements.aspx). The Google cache didn't have a lot of information.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Nauru) says Australians are allowed to apply for a visa, but I don't know how current the information is.

Comment: So all the official agencies are telling you it's ok to go but you're still unsure because of a rumour ? Where did you even read about this ?

Comment: @blackbird the "official agencies" aren't saying anything.

Comment: nor do they say you need special authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Australians can visit Nauru as tourists, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=AU&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=NR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the "bible of Airlines"

It also says you don't need a visa, but can apply for an approval letter by e-mail at visa@naurugov.nr

Comment: What's an entry letter ?

Comment: @blackbird A letter from the immigration authority saying you're allowed to enter, with your personal information